# Integrate existing TouchUI component into RTE - AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I'm looking to see if it's possible to integrate an existing AEM Component that I've developed (lets say button component) into the RTE.

I've read the following blog posts

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/01/aem-6-sp1-touchui-richtext-editor-color-picker-plugin.html

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-rich-text-editor-rte-browse-insert-image.html

I've also read the documentation (which is non existent).

I'm not looking to recreate the exact same component just for the RTE, this would need us to maintain two separate code bases, recreate the custom logic we have in the already existing component which has been tested and automation.

But most of all, go against best practices as we want everything to be agnostic.

Comment: When you say "integrate a component into RTE", what does that mean? Are you looking to develop a *plugin* for RTE?

Comment: Not looking to develop a separate plugin, I'm looking to use an existing component that I've already built in the RTE. e.g. A button component that's already built, I want to use in the rte to save me having to build a separate plugin with the same functionality.

Comment: how do you plan on using a "component" in RTE? do you just want to insert HTML from a component to RTE? do you want to pick blocks of HTML (components) to be added to RTE ?